# DISQUS.reset does not work

Tags: javascript, ajax, disqus

Has anyone had any success getting the DISQUS.reset function to work for a embedded thread? Each time I try to run DISQUS.reset it says that the function is undefined. Before I call reset I make sure that the javascript file has been loaded.

Any idea what's going on? Did they replace this?

Comment: Are you doing it like the example [here](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472107-using-disqus-on-ajax-sites)?

Comment: Yup that's what I'm doing and that's where I found out about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still not implemented en DISQUS 2012... disable it to use DISQUS.reset.

> Notable features and functionalities not yet supported
>
> Support is coming soon for the following features:
>
> 1. **AJAX-driven sites using the DISQUS.reset variable**
> 2. The onNewComment callback
> 3. HTTPS Non-English languages and
>      translations
> 4. Image Uploads
> 5. Mod/Admin Identification
>
> *While not all features previously supported have made it into Disqus 2012, we'd love to hear your feedback via our support page.

http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/526768-introducing-disqus-2012-and-f-a-q-